# Knockout template not binding on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-9

I have an issue with knockout and IE9, everything works perfectly fine on IE 10-11, but on IE9 the content from the template is not displayed, I debugged the JS code and the binding is happening, and is not throwing any error, but when the binding is 'done' the content is not append to the specified container, does anybody have some idea how I can figure out what is the error? Cause as I wrote I debugged the code and when I call ko.applyBindings() everything works fine, no exception thrown, but the content of the template does not appear in the container.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the template/s to the top of the body, above all the items that will be rendered to the screen.  I have found in the past that this has worked for me with IE9.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will try on Monday and let you know if works

Comment: Well that fixed the issue, not sure why my question was voted -1, the rendering was working fine before without moving the templates to the top of the body, and they are generated dynamically on the server so I was appending them in the body.